# How to count number of same values only when two other columns are not blank excell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am currently using `=COUNTIF` to count all values that are equal to `5331` but I want to change this so that it only counts values that are equal to `5331` in column `B:B` when values held in `E:E` and `F:F` are not empty.

I currently have this: `= COUNTIF(MSL!B:B, "5490")+COUNTIF(MSL!E:E, "<>")+COUNTIF(MSL!F:F, "<>")` but this does not return the expected result (I expect it to still count if values are blank, I haven't figured out how to implement `NOT` logic yet)

How could I go about implementing this?

Many Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Try looking into COUNTIFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use =COUNTIFS() for multiple conditions

```
=COUNTIFS(MSL!B:B, "5490", MSL!E:E, "<>", MSL!F:F, "<>")
```